# Using Pusher in Vue for a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, pusher

I am trying to use Pusher inside a Chrome extension I am writing in Vue.

The problem I have is that Chrome is refusing to load a script used by Pusher's pusher-js library (And I see the same error if I try and utilise the Pusher JS file directly, rather than as part of the library) (Obviously the key and session are shown in full in the actual error!)

> pusher.js:1128 Refused to load the script 'https://stats.pusher.com/timeline/v2/jsonp/1?session=XXX%3D&bundle=MQ%3D%3D&key=XXX' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

The culprit is this line in pusher's JS:

`head.insertBefore(self.script, head.firstChild);`

I have tried lots of different things in my Manifest, including, of course, adding https://stats.pusher.com like this:

`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://stats.pusher.com https://js.pusher.com; object-src 'self'"`

But nothing works. It DOES work if I build the same code example outside of a Vue extension as a 'pure Javascript' project, but I would prefer to use Vue if I can. I suspect this happens because:

Firstly: Pusher is calling an external script from within a script rather than calling it directly

Secondly: I am calling the Pusher library outside of a Javascript file

This is my App.vue which is served from popup.js:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import pusher from 'pusher';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      messages: '',
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const pusher = new Pusher('xxx', {
      cluster: 'eu',
      forceTLS: true,
    });
    this.channel = pusher.subscribe('realtime-updates');
    const channel = pusher.subscribe('realtime-updates');
    channel.bind('things', data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Note in the above example I tried copying the Pusher Javacript library in as a local file and setting a path to it in Webpack but I see exactly the same error if I use the official NPM.

Appreciate any help,

Thanks!

Comment: Since using external scripts in the privileged context of an extension is a bad idea, I suggest patching the library or use a different one. If you're stuck with this one then at least load it inside a *sandbox* iframe (it runs in its own origin so it can't access the extension directly) and use postMessage for communication.

Comment: Thanks. I actually came back to say I have been investigating more and think I may have found a solution. However, I am not sure how well it addresses your very vaild points here. 

No solution is better than me posting a bad solution If I work out something that seems safe, I will post it here- the idea of using a Sandbox iframe is new to me though

Comment: As the error is around the Pusher Stats endpoint, you could simply disable the stats collection. https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020083153-How-can-I-turn-off-Stats-collection-in-Channels-

Comment: Try setting `content_security_policy` to `"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"` - that string works for me everytime I need something hacky in my extensions